# Date formatting in Store

Tags: extjs, extjs5

How to format store data, In my case it is returning date and I am binding it to Comobox

> ```
> var comboDate = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
> displayField: 'date',
> valueField: 'date',
> store: {
>     type: 'webapi',
>     autoLoad: true,        
>     api: {
>         read: 'api/Report/GetDate'
>     }        
> }
> });
> ```

It is binding it as "Mon May 9 00:00:00 EDT 2016"

I tried few things to resolve it -

> ```
>  dateFormat: 'c'
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>    renderer: Utility.Formatting.ShortDateTime
> ```

Please suggest me how can we apply Date formatting in Store

**UPDATING**
Here i am adding the complete code - I am trying to bind date to a combobox in a grid.

> ```
>  header: 'From Date', dataIndex: 'date',  editor: comboDate, renderer: comboBoxDateRenderer(comboDate)
> ```

```
 var comboBoxDateRenderer = function (comboDate) {
return function (value) {       
    var idx = comboDate.store.find(comboDate.valueField, value);//Ext.util.Format.date(value, "Y-m-d")
    var rec = comboDate.store.getAt(idx);
    return (rec === null ? '' : rec.get(comboDate.displayField));
};
    }

var comboDate = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
displayField: 'date',
valueField: 'date',
//dateFormat: 'c',
store: {
    type: 'webapi',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: [
          { name: 'date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' }
    ],
    api: {
        read: 'api/Report/GetDate'
    }        
}
});
```

Comment: simply add format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' as a field into combobox

Comment: Added as you suggested but no difference

Answer (score 0):

The value is a standard date object. You can use XTemplates to format the displayfield: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a37

List Template:

```
tpl: Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">'+
    '<div class="x-boundlist-item">' +
    '{[Ext.util.Format.date(values.date, "d/m/y")]}' +
    '</div>'+
    '</tpl>'
),
```

Displayfield Template:

```
displayTpl: Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">'+
    '{[Ext.util.Format.date(values.date, "d/m/y")]}'+
    '</tpl>'
),
```

Keep in mind that this is only pure formatting the display output.